# How to get projects locations in Eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write a a java application which gets all the projects locations path, in eclipse workspace.
I can get the projects list in a workspace 
(list under: Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/)

But how can I get each of those projects locations ?
(I cant see any file in those projects which give me it's location)

Thanks

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: I checked each folder under Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/ but didnt see how to get the real folder project location.

Comment: Is this an Eclipse plugin you are writing? This is fairly straightforward for a plugin (perhaps running in a headless RCP). For a plain Java program there are no APIs to do this.

Comment: Check out the BulkImportPlugin, maybe the source code contains hints how to do it. http://github.com/srasul/Eclipse-Bulk-Import/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

import `org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace` and you have to write the code like below http://help.eclipse.org/luna/rtopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspace.html

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(); 
File workspaceDirectory = workspace.getRoot().getLocation().toFile()
```

Check these link

http://www.coderanch.com/t/453807/vc/find-Workspace-Java-code-Eclipse

http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace

Answer (score 0):

If this project is run from within eclipse you can add program variables to your program.
Add ${workspace_loc} in the Run Configurations, tab Arguments, Program arguments.

Then this little snippet can list all folders (possibly projects)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));

    File dir = new File(args[0]);
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if(file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().startsWith("."))
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

Excluding folders that starts with dot, excludes .metadata